# How to activate the auto focus in ZXing bar code scanning app

Tags: win-universal-app, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner, autofocus

I am working on a barcode scanning app and it works well, but the user has to toutch the screen in order to force the camera to focus on the code, then the app can detect the code.
The question is: How to activate the auto-focus?

It's UWP app.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can I see something of your code?
In my app I'm using the ZXingScannerFragment and I this function:

```
public ZXingSurfaceView scanner;
public void AutoFocus()
{
   try
   {
       scanner.AutoFocus();
   }
   catch
   {
       throw;
   }
}
```